# What are specifications for pagination dots for Android 5?

Tags: pagination, material-design

I have been searching about this and looking into the documentation, but failed. Is it forgotten by Google? Or it's hidden somewhere I didn't notice?

Example:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain or show what you mean by pagination dots?

Comment: @tohster See bottom of [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pihO2.png). Image is for iOS though, but I think you catch my drift. In iOS, it's called a pageviewer (UIPageViewController to be exact).

Comment: Addendum: In Android, it's popularized as `ViewPagerIndicator` (3rd-party library) since it's an indicator used on pagination (`ViewPager`), but yeah, Google haven't provided the API for that, the developer has to implement it by themselves.

Answer (score 4):

There *are* some uses of pagination dots in the android system or in google apps.

If you take a look at the default lollipop app launcher or the home screen, you'll see them at the bottom of the screen.

[image]  [image]

Also if you take a look at any google app that offers a tutorial, you will also find some.

E.g. Google Drive:

[image] [image]

(Btw. a great example of badly placed text in a translated app...)

- They're at the bottom
- Don't overlay any content
- Placed in a separated area
- ...and not clickable.

Comment: Thanks for examples : ) But I still wonder if the usage and appearance (color, diameter, distance, etc) are exactly defined in any Google official document? If not, is there a de facto standard for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't recall an app that has something that you mean, unless it's custom made. Meaning: Android does not have pagination dots. Usually tabs are used, in combination with swiping. ([Check out the image below Scrollable Tabs](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html))